# Android SDK Media Recorder. State 4

Tags: android, sdk, media-player, state, android-2.2-froyo

I'm just at the end of developing a quick Android App.

Minor problem. What's state 4?

I'm using MediaPlayer and every time I run the app I get an error stating that Media Player "start()" is first called in state 0, then state 4.

Does anyone know what state 4 is?

I can figure out the problem if I know the states such as state 1 and 2...

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is "What is state 4" and you were given a very good answer. You should accept that answer. Go and ask another question if your code is not working yet.

Answer (score 7):

This is from MediaPlayer.h in the Android source:

```
enum media_player_states {
  MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR        = 0,
  MEDIA_PLAYER_IDLE               = 1 << 0,
  MEDIA_PLAYER_INITIALIZED        = 1 << 1,
  MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARING          = 1 << 2,
  MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARED           = 1 << 3,
  MEDIA_PLAYER_DECODED            = 1 << 4,
  MEDIA_PLAYER_STARTED            = 1 << 5,
  MEDIA_PLAYER_PAUSED             = 1 << 6,
  MEDIA_PLAYER_STOPPED            = 1 << 7,
  MEDIA_PLAYER_PLAYBACK_COMPLETE  = 1 << 8
};
```

Therefore 0 would be MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR and 4 would be MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARING.
Did you call prepare() or prepareAsync() before calling start()?

These are the MediaRecorder states:

```
enum media_recorder_states {
  MEDIA_RECORDER_ERROR                 =      0,
  MEDIA_RECORDER_IDLE                  = 1 << 0,
  MEDIA_RECORDER_INITIALIZED           = 1 << 1,
  MEDIA_RECORDER_DATASOURCE_CONFIGURED = 1 << 2,
  MEDIA_RECORDER_PREPARED              = 1 << 3,
  MEDIA_RECORDER_RECORDING             = 1 << 4,
};
```

So for recording, state 4 is MEDIA_RECORDER_DATASOURCE_CONFIGURED.

Comment: Here's what I've implemented in my code. I created a global in my class/"extends": `final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();` When I'm about to initiate MediaPlayer I call `reset()`, then a try and catch statement with `setAudioStreamType, setDataSource(/sdcard/audio.3gp), and prepareAsync()` in order, in the `try` block. That's when I finally call `start();`

Comment: I didn't add prepare yet. Should it be directly after the try and catch for `prepareAsync()`?

Comment: When you use prepareAsync(), you must implement OnPreparedListener, call setOnPreparedListener() and wait for the onPrepared() callback before calling start().

Comment: If you are playing back a file, you can use prepare() instead of prepareAsync(). In that case you can call start() immediately after prepare() and don't need to implement the listener.

Comment: Moving forward very much so. Now, I imported media `OnPreparedListener`, `implements OnPreparedListener`, added `setOnPreparedListener(this)` to the `try` statements where `setdatasource, audiostreamtype, etc` are, added `mediaPlayer.prepare()` in its own try/catch block AFTER the try/catch block for `setOnPreparedListener, setsource, prepareAsync`, and moved `mediaPlayer.start()` to and external `public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) { mediaPlayer.start();}` function. Now, I getting prepareAsync called in state 4, "Level E", with Illegal exception for MediaPlayer.prepare, "Level W".

Comment: Did you see my previous comment? You use prepare() OR prepareAsync(), not both.

Comment: It took me a while to type my previous comment. I'm updating the code now using `.prepare()` over `.prepareAsync()`...

Comment: After modifying, I placed `.prepare()` AFTER `.reset()` and the try/catch block that incorporates `.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  .setDataSource("/sdcard/audio.3gp");` With those changes I receive Level W error that `.prepare()` has failed and Level E error that `.start()` is called in state 0, more than likely from the failed `.prepare()`. Because prepare is failing, that has something to do with the way I'm setting up the stream. May be it cannot find the .3gp file. On the Andorid Emulator I also cannot find any audio files in storage.

Comment: I moved to a file already on my sdcard and the prepare went through. In my log I am seeing `start() in    invoke 72   start     start() out` Does that mean the player is stopping as soon as it is starting?